# Laravel: The cart does not contain rowId ce5452f389f041ab17e46324cc050c0d

Tags: php, laravel, shopping-cart

My code works perfect on the local machine, i deployed but the delete, add and update function do not work well that is why i get the following errow "The cart does not contain rowId ce5452f389f041ab17e46324cc050c0d."

Here is my controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $cartItems=Cart::content();
        return view('cart.index',compact('cartItems'));
    }


    public function addItem($id)
    {
        $product=Product::find($id);

        Cart::add($id,$product->name,1,$product->price,['size'=>'medium']);

        return back();
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
//        dd(Cart::content());
//        dd($request->all());
        Cart::update($id,['qty'=>$request->qty,"options"=>['size'=>$request->size]]);
        return back();
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Cart::remove($id);
        return back();
    }
```

MY "MODEL" please be patient with me, i only seek understanding if i appear to be some sort of slow

```
namespace Gloudemans\Shoppingcart;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Session\SessionManager;
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Contracts\Buyable;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Exceptions\UnknownModelException;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Exceptions\InvalidRowIDException;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Exceptions\CartAlreadyStoredException;

class Cart
{
    const DEFAULT_INSTANCE = 'default';

    /**
     * Instance of the session manager.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Session\SessionManager
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * Instance of the event dispatcher.
     * 
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher
     */
    private $events;

    /**
     * Holds the current cart instance.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $instance;

    /**
     * Cart constructor.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Session\SessionManager      $session
     * @param \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher $events
     */
    public function __construct(SessionManager $session, Dispatcher $events)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->events = $events;

        $this->instance(self::DEFAULT_INSTANCE);
    }

    /**
     * Set the current cart instance.
     *
     * @param string|null $instance
     * @return \Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart
     */
    public function instance($instance = null)
    {
        $instance = $instance ?: self::DEFAULT_INSTANCE;

        $this->instance = sprintf('%s.%s', 'cart', $instance);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the current cart instance.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function currentInstance()
    {
        return str_replace('cart.', '', $this->instance);
    }

    /**
     * Add an item to the cart.
     *
     * @param mixed     $id
     * @param mixed     $name
     * @param int|float $qty
     * @param float     $price
     * @param array     $options
     * @return \Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem
     */
    public function add($id, $name = null, $qty = null, $price = null, array $options = [])
    {
        if ($this->isMulti($id)) {
            return array_map(function ($item) {
                return $this->add($item);
            }, $id);
        }

        $cartItem = $this->createCartItem($id, $name, $qty, $price, $options);

        $content = $this->getContent();

        if ($content->has($cartItem->rowId)) {
            $cartItem->qty += $content->get($cartItem->rowId)->qty;
        }

        $content->put($cartItem->rowId, $cartItem);

        $this->events->fire('cart.added', $cartItem);

        $this->session->put($this->instance, $content);

        return $cartItem;
    }

    /**
     * Update the cart item with the given rowId.
     *
     * @param string $rowId
     * @param mixed  $qty
     * @return \Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem
     */
    public function update($rowId, $qty)
    {
        $cartItem = $this->get($rowId);

        if ($qty instanceof Buyable) {
            $cartItem->updateFromBuyable($qty);
        } elseif (is_array($qty)) {
            $cartItem->updateFromArray($qty);
        } else {
            $cartItem->qty = $qty;
        }

        $content = $this->getContent();

        if ($rowId !== $cartItem->rowId) {
            $content->pull($rowId);

            if ($content->has($cartItem->rowId)) {
                $existingCartItem = $this->get($cartItem->rowId);
                $cartItem->setQuantity($existingCartItem->qty + $cartItem->qty);
            }
        }

        if ($cartItem->qty <= 0) {
            $this->remove($cartItem->rowId);
            return;
        } else {
            $content->put($cartItem->rowId, $cartItem);
        }

        $this->events->fire('cart.updated', $cartItem);

        $this->session->put($this->instance, $content);

        return $cartItem;
    }

    /**
     * Remove the cart item with the given rowId from the cart.
     *
     * @param string $rowId
     * @return void
     */
    public function remove($rowId)
    {
        $cartItem = $this->get($rowId);

        $content = $this->getContent();

        $content->pull($cartItem->rowId);

        $this->events->fire('cart.removed', $cartItem);

        $this->session->put($this->instance, $content);
    }

    /**
     * Get a cart item from the cart by its rowId.
     *
     * @param string $rowId
     * @return \Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem
     */
    public function get($rowId)
    {
        $content = $this->getContent();

        if ( ! $content->has($rowId))
            throw new InvalidRowIDException("The cart does not contain rowId {$rowId}.");

        return $content->get($rowId);
    }

    /**
     * Destroy the current cart instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function destroy()
    {
        $this->session->remove($this->instance);
    }

    /**
     * Get the content of the cart.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function content()
    {
        if (is_null($this->session->get($this->instance))) {
            return new Collection([]);
        }

        return $this->session->get($this->instance);
    }

    /**
     * Get the number of items in the cart.
     *
     * @return int|float
     */
    public function count()
    {
        $content = $this->getContent();

        return $content->sum('qty');
    }

    /**
     * Get the total price of the items in the cart.
     *
     * @param int    $decimals
     * @param string $decimalPoint
     * @param string $thousandSeperator
     * @return string
     */
    public function total($decimals = null, $decimalPoint = null, $thousandSeperator = null)
    {
        $content = $this->getContent();

        $total = $content->reduce(function ($total, CartItem $cartItem) {
            return $total + ($cartItem->qty * $cartItem->priceTax);
        }, 0);

        return $this->numberFormat($total, $decimals, $decimalPoint, $thousandSeperator);
    }

    /**
     * Get the total tax of the items in the cart.
     *
     * @param int    $decimals
     * @param string $decimalPoint
     * @param string $thousandSeperator
     * @return float
     */
    public function tax($decimals = null, $decimalPoint = null, $thousandSeperator = null)
    {
        $content = $this->getContent();

        $tax = $content->reduce(function ($tax, CartItem $cartItem) {
            return $tax + ($cartItem->qty * $cartItem->tax);
        }, 0);

        return $this->numberFormat($tax, $decimals, $decimalPoint, $thousandSeperator);
    }

    /**
     * Get the subtotal (total - tax) of the items in the cart.
     *
     * @param int    $decimals
     * @param string $decimalPoint
     * @param string $thousandSeperator
     * @return float
     */
    public function subtotal($decimals = null, $decimalPoint = null, $thousandSeperator = null)
    {
        $content = $this->getContent();

        $subTotal = $content->reduce(function ($subTotal, CartItem $cartItem) {
            return $subTotal + ($cartItem->qty * $cartItem->price);
        }, 0);

        return $this->numberFormat($subTotal, $decimals, $decimalPoint, $thousandSeperator);
    }

    /**
     * Search the cart content for a cart item matching the given search closure.
     *
     * @param \Closure $search
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function search(Closure $search)
    {
        $content = $this->getContent();

        return $content->filter($search);
    }

    /**
     * Associate the cart item with the given rowId with the given model.
     *
     * @param string $rowId
     * @param mixed  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function associate($rowId, $model)
    {
        if(is_string($model) && ! class_exists($model)) {
            throw new UnknownModelException("The supplied model {$model} does not exist.");
        }

        $cartItem = $this->get($rowId);

        $cartItem->associate($model);

        $content = $this->getContent();

        $content->put($cartItem->rowId, $cartItem);

        $this->session->put($this->instance, $content);
    }

    /**
     * Set the tax rate for the cart item with the given rowId.
     *
     * @param string    $rowId
     * @param int|float $taxRate
     * @return void
     */
    public function setTax($rowId, $taxRate)
    {
        $cartItem = $this->get($rowId);

        $cartItem->setTaxRate($taxRate);

        $content = $this->getContent();

        $content->put($cartItem->rowId, $cartItem);

        $this->session->put($this->instance, $content);
    }

    /**
     * Store an the current instance of the cart.
     *
     * @param mixed $identifier
     * @return void
     */
    public function store($identifier)
    {
        $content = $this->getContent();

        if ($this->storedCartWithIdentifierExists($identifier)) {
            throw new CartAlreadyStoredException("A cart with identifier {$identifier} was already stored.");
        }

        $this->getConnection()->table($this->getTableName())->insert([
            'identifier' => $identifier,
            'instance' => $this->currentInstance(),
            'content' => serialize($content)
        ]);

        $this->events->fire('cart.stored');
    }

    /**
     * Restore the cart with the given identifier.
     *
     * @param mixed $identifier
     * @return void
     */
    public function restore($identifier)
    {
        if( ! $this->storedCartWithIdentifierExists($identifier)) {
            return;
        }

        $stored = $this->getConnection()->table($this->getTableName())
            ->where('identifier', $identifier)->first();

        $storedContent = unserialize($stored->content);

        $currentInstance = $this->currentInstance();

        $this->instance($stored->instance);

        $content = $this->getContent();

        foreach ($storedContent as $cartItem) {
            $content->put($cartItem->rowId, $cartItem);
        }

        $this->events->fire('cart.restored');

        $this->session->put($this->instance, $content);

        $this->instance($currentInstance);

        $this->getConnection()->table($this->getTableName())
            ->where('identifier', $identifier)->delete();
    }

    /**
     * Magic method to make accessing the total, tax and subtotal properties possible.
     *
     * @param string $attribute
     * @return float|null
     */
    public function __get($attribute)
    {
        if($attribute === 'total') {
            return $this->total();
        }

        if($attribute === 'tax') {
            return $this->tax();
        }

        if($attribute === 'subtotal') {
            return $this->subtotal();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the carts content, if there is no cart content set yet, return a new empty Collection
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    protected function getContent()
    {
        $content = $this->session->has($this->instance)
            ? $this->session->get($this->instance)
            : new Collection;

        return $content;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new CartItem from the supplied attributes.
     *
     * @param mixed     $id
     * @param mixed     $name
     * @param int|float $qty
     * @param float     $price
     * @param array     $options
     * @return \Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem
     */
    private function createCartItem($id, $name, $qty, $price, array $options)
    {
        if ($id instanceof Buyable) {
            $cartItem = CartItem::fromBuyable($id, $qty ?: []);
            $cartItem->setQuantity($name ?: 1);
            $cartItem->associate($id);
        } elseif (is_array($id)) {
            $cartItem = CartItem::fromArray($id);
            $cartItem->setQuantity($id['qty']);
        } else {
            $cartItem = CartItem::fromAttributes($id, $name, $price, $options);
            $cartItem->setQuantity($qty);
        }

        $cartItem->setTaxRate(config('cart.tax'));

        return $cartItem;
    }

    /**
     * Check if the item is a multidimensional array or an array of Buyables.
     *
     * @param mixed $item
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isMulti($item)
    {
        if ( ! is_array($item)) return false;

        return is_array(head($item)) || head($item) instanceof Buyable;
    }

    /**
     * @param $identifier
     * @return bool
     */
    private function storedCartWithIdentifierExists($identifier)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->table($this->getTableName())->where('identifier', $identifier)->exists();
    }

    /**
     * Get the database connection.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Connection
     */
    private function getConnection()
    {
        $connectionName = $this->getConnectionName();

        return app(DatabaseManager::class)->connection($connectionName);
    }

    /**
     * Get the database table name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getTableName()
    {
        return config('cart.database.table', 'shoppingcart');
    }

    /**
     * Get the database connection name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getConnectionName()
    {
        $connection = config('cart.database.connection');

        return is_null($connection) ? config('database.default') : $connection;
    }

    /**
     * Get the Formated number
     *
     * @param $value
     * @param $decimals
     * @param $decimalPoint
     * @param $thousandSeperator
     * @return string
     */
    private function numberFormat($value, $decimals, $decimalPoint, $thousandSeperator)
    {
        if(is_null($decimals)){
            $decimals = is_null(config('cart.format.decimals')) ? 2 : config('cart.format.decimals');
        }
        if(is_null($decimalPoint)){
            $decimalPoint = is_null(config('cart.format.decimal_point')) ? '.' : config('cart.format.decimal_point');
        }
        if(is_null($thousandSeperator)){
            $thousandSeperator = is_null(config('cart.format.thousand_seperator')) ? ',' : config('cart.format.thousand_seperator');
        }

        return number_format($value, $decimals, $decimalPoint, $thousandSeperator);
    }
}
```

MY "VIEW"

```
@foreach($cartItems as $cartItem)
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-style: solid">{{$cartItem->name}}</td>
                    <td style="border-style: solid">{{$cartItem->price}}</td>
                    <td  style="border-style: solid">
                        {!! Form::open(['route' => ['cart.update',$cartItem->rowId], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
                        <input name="qty" type="text" value="{{$cartItem->qty}}">

                    </td>

                    <td style="border-style: solid">
                        <input style="float: left"  type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Ok">
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-style: solid">

                        <form action="{{route('cart.destroy',$cartItem->rowId)}}"  method="POST" >
                            {{csrf_field()}}
                            {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                            <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

My inspector shows the rowID, i can understand that the rowID is generated by the cart when i add the item but where to located this rowID is something different.

```
   <tr>
                    <td style="border-style: solid">ASGHJSDFGHJDF</td>
                    <td style="border-style: solid">56</td>
                    <td  style="border-style: solid">
                        <form method="POST" action="http://rorisangmaimane.co.za/cart/ce5452f389f041ab17e46324cc050c0d" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="iXJ3ncGwro7lVA07Mph4rbZloVF1UTQ0m8mlmpK6">
                        <input name="qty" type="text" value="2">

                    </td>

                    <td style="border-style: solid">
                        <input style="float: left"  type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Ok">
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-style: solid">

                        <form action="http://rorisangmaimane.co.za/cart/ce5452f389f041ab17e46324cc050c0d"  method="POST" >
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="iXJ3ncGwro7lVA07Mph4rbZloVF1UTQ0m8mlmpK6">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                            <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: can you show us your models? and the code where you get that error

Comment: I got also the same problem. Did you already fix this? @dawn

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem. But my problem happen when user click the update/remove button twice at a same time. 
I solved the issue by following ways - 
First check whether the `rowId` is available or not. Then implement actions -

```
       $cart = Cart::content()->where('rowId',$id);
       if($cart->isNotEmpty()){
           Cart::remove($id);
       }
```

Same way in the updated functions also.